Recovering old package from Macports - archived somewhere?
I was in the process of working through how to get the local web-server version of Joplin 3 (based on the mobile version) compiled on macOS 10.13 High Sierra (because the GUI absolutely will not, being dependent on features that didn't exist until later OS versions), and writing up a detailed tutorial on the process. The only way to do this is with Node.js 21, because 22 and later are inoperable on macOS 10.13. Can't use Homebrew for this. MacPorts handily provided Node 21 and the ICU 74 it depends on.
Then I needed to reinstall Node 21 for some reason or other (stopped running due to some library being upgraded and the old one removed). THIS VERY WEEK, MacPorts decided to delete Node 21 from its offerings, right out from under me, and forces an upgrade to 22, which won't compile on my OS. So, all this work for nothing.
Is there some repo somewhere with older MacPorts packages that they no longer want to provide support for? It seems unlikely to me that the package I need has disappeared off the entire Internet forever.
Trying to do something like sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants nodejs21@21.7.3 fails; it just forcibly tries to install @22.whatever anyway.

Old versions seem to be available on https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases. Otherwise, https://trac.macports.org might be the better place to ask this.

Also, https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/tree/master/devel/nodejs20 is still in the repository, so you may be able to build it yourself.

Ah! I think that github repo is what I'm looking for. As for trac.macports.org, that's been a dead server for a while now. Through Wayback, I found some info there on how to revert to a previous package, as long as it was still locally installed, but something about this boogered my installation, such that node 22 had wiped out node 21.  Nothing I found in the trac.macports.org archive really addressed getting packages MacPorts had abandoned/removed.

I found the Node 21 Portfile and even after commenting out the livecheck stuff at the end of it, I still get nodejs21 is replaced by nodejs22 followed by an attempt to install 22.  Not sure what to change/disable next to get it to stop that. I'm more familiar with Homebrew. I searched the man port page for "local" and didn't find anything pertinent, so I'm not sure how to tell it "use local files only, don't check GitHub for updates during this installation".

Software development questions are off-topic on AD, but can be asked on StackOverflow. Still think you would get better support by using the mac-ports mailing list though.

trac.macports.org is not dead.

This isn't software development, it's software installation. But yes, MacPorts's own mailing list might have more immediate answers. As for trac.macports.org, for a long time now it's been telling me "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.59 (Debian) Server at trac.macports.org Port 443", which is the sort of message you get when a site has been taken offline but still has a running webserver. People here saying it still works prompted me to try in a different browser; suddenly the site worked properly. Maybe a browser extension of some kind interfering.

Nodejsv21 is an unstable release.  All the odd numbered versions are.  They go out of support 6 months from release.  Nodejs21 final release was 4/10/24.
From https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases

Major Node.js versions enter Current release status
for six months, which gives library authors time to add support for
them. After six months, odd-numbered releases (9, 11, etc.) become
unsupported, and even-numbered releases (10, 12, etc.) move to Active
LTS status and are ready for general use. LTS release status is
"long-term support", which typically guarantees that critical bugs
will be fixed for a total of 30 months. Production applications should
only use Active LTS or Maintenance LTS releases.

So yes, MacPorts is going to stop shipping it.  Does the tool you are trying to build ONLY support nodejs21?  Even-numbered releases for quite a ways back are available.
trac.macports.org is anything but dead.  This link may be useful to you:
https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort
If the older port file is still retrievable.

Thanks. That might have worked (will take more testing). I was able to install node 20 via MacPorts and the npm and yarn that will use it. The Joplin stuff seemed OK using those versions, but just up to a point. When I get the Joplin mini-webserver running, it launches with an error of On-device testing failed with an exception: TypeError: Failed to execute 'write' on 'FileSystemSyncAccessHandle': parameter 1 is not of type 'ArrayBufferView'. (Calling writeFile). But then it does load the web-app. This is not an error occurring under Node 21. Dunno if it will actually work.

But this might (might not) address my specific use-case, not the general question. It's likely some people are going to need to "recover" specific old packages from MacPorts. So a full answer would be like "Get the old Portfile from GitHub thus .... Then do X and Y to prevent MacPorts from checking for and trying to use a newer version anyway. Do Z to force it to use an already-download local package to install."

PS: As for trac.macports.org, it appeared to be a dead stick in my browser (for a long time now) but when I switched to another it suddenly worked again. Probably interference from some browser extension.

@S.McCandlish The MacPorts howto is about as specific as it can get, actually delving down to retrieving specific git commits.  If you think there is a need for more specific documentation, I have no doubt that MacPorts would welcome a PR.
